# JavaScript runtime event loop prior art

Tags: javascript, event-loop

The only high profile implementation of the event loop model I can name, other than so-called "reactive" systems that came later, is the JavaScript runtime.

Was there much prior art of the event-loop architectural model before the implementation of the JavaScript runtime in web browsers?

What other software systems used this architectural model around the time of its original implementation in Netscape?

Comment: Please explain the downvote and I will attempt to refine the question.

Comment: Well, there's...[the Windows operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). And I'm sure that didn't innovate the concept.

Comment: Re the downvote, some people view asking questions that are clearly not suitable to the SO format as a "lack of research" and vote down on that basis. (I don't.) The question is far too broad for SO. More in the [help].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was unable to find any sources but as far as I can remember run loops have been around for a long time. They are a core pattern in computer science and probably the most famous example is Microsoft Windows OS.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) explains more yet oddly omits JavaScript in it's text.